# ASUS ROG GL553VE (aka FX53VE-MS74) External Monitor Connection(s)

Tags: external-display, asus-laptop, nvidia-geforce, displayport, usb-3.1-type-c

When I attach a 3840x1080 monitor capable of 144Hz through HDMI, all I am getting is 60Hz.

There is a USB 3.1 Gen 1 Type-C port, but I cannot confirm that DisplayPort functionality is implemented.

Is there a way to get 144Hz signal out of the GL553VE, given that the Nvidia GeForce 1050Ti supports it?

Comment: Your laptop does not support DisplayPort over USB Type-C Gen 1.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for the response. Is there any other way to get 144Hz signal from this laptop?